# How do I hide a Toolbar when scrolling down a ListView in Android? (Xamarin)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Toolbar and a TabLayout at the top of the screen, with a ViewPager below. The ViewPager shows a different fragment for each tab, but each of those fragments is essentially just a RelativeLayout with a ListView inside it.
I want to make it such that when the ListView is scrolled down, the Toolbar will hide itself (moves out of sight towards the top of screen), and when it is scrolled up, the Toolbar will appear again.

I tried following a few guides, but it doesn't seem to be working. Not to mention that everything I can find about this is either outdated or uses a RecyclerView just below the AppBarLayout. I need a ViewPager for the tabs, so I can't have a RecylerView there.

I'm using API level 30, and I'm testing on an emulated Pixel 2.

This is what my XML looks like:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
                                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="32dp"
                                                 android:layout_below="@id/title"
                                                 android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                                                 app:tabMinWidth="96dp"
                                                 app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                                                 app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                                                 app:tabMode="scrollable">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="@string/tab_1"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="@string/tab_2"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="@string/tab_3"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/content"
                                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
                                       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to build with Android Studio, if it work you just need to copy paste the xml to your Xamarin.Android

Comment: Using an AppBarLayout allows your Toolbar and other views to react to scroll events in a sibling view marked with a ScrollingViewBehavior. You could try to remove it.